# How can I output the lines from the input file into a new file?

Tags: c++

My code is already getting the output file and can write code into it but it only writes the last line from the input file and not any of the others.

```
string output_file_name(string file_name) 
{
    string output_file_name;
    file_name.pop_back();
    string ch = "o";
    output_file_name = file_name + ch;
    return output_file_name;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    string file_name;
    string line;
    string token;

    file_name = argv[1];

    ifstream input_file(file_name);
    ofstream output_file(output_file_name(file_name));

    if (input_file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(input_file, line))
        {
            output_file << line << endl;
        }
    }

    input_file.close();  //closing the input file

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First off, you should use the OS for copying files; it's optimized for that.

Comment: Remove your `stringstream` statement, it's not needed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what do you mean by using the OS?

Comment: In Linux, `cp source_file target_file`.  In MSDOS:  `copy source_file target_file`.  You may want to see if your OS has an API for file copying.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ah okay, well I don't think I can do that for this project

Comment: Side note: Never use `argv` until after confirming that it is safe to do so by checking `argc`.

Comment: @user4581301 how would you check argc? Are you checking to see if it is NULL?

Comment: In order to know that there is an `argv[1]`, the number of supplied arguments, `argc`, must be 2 or greater. A simple `if` statement takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to close `output_file` as well. Otherwise, the following code works for me:

```cpp
    string output_file_name(string file_name) {
        string output_file_name;
        file_name.pop_back();
        string ch = "o";
        output_file_name = file_name + ch;
        return output_file_name;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        string file_name;
        string line;
        string token;
    
        file_name = argv[1];
    
        ifstream input_file(file_name);
        ofstream output_file(output_file_name(file_name));
    
        if (input_file.is_open()) {
            while (getline(input_file, line)) {
                output_file << line << endl;
            }
        }
    
        output_file.close(); // be sure to close the output file as well
        input_file.close();  // closing the input file
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: oh yeah I have a function for that but I forgot to include it, thanks anyway though

Comment: Sidenote: File stream destructors close the file in case you forget. As soon as the stream object goes out of scope, it closes. If you scope the stream tightly, you'll almost never have to manually close

Comment: @user4581301 would it not be good practice to close it anyway or is it not necessary at all?

Comment: A coin toss. There is no significant penalty or advantage I can see here. Personally I would leave it out because manually closing it could be interpreted as you intended to do something with the file stream, like reopening it, after closing.